# Opencv-python boxPoints order

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, contour

Hi for a project I am trying to detect different paintings in a gallery.
To score my object detector I need to give the top-left and bottom-right corner of my estimated bounding box to my scoring system.

However I've noticed that the order in which cv2.boxPoints() returns its corners is not the same for each detection.

I've drawn the corners on my image and as you can see on my included picture, the green bounding box is my detection and it's corners are in light blue. However on the right there is another bounding box (false positive detection) but the corners are in the wrong order. How can this be fixed so that I can always get the top-left and bottom-right corner?

Don't pay attention to the red box, this is the ground truth label and is working as intended.

```
    for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area >= 5000:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
        box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
        boxes.append(box[1::2])
        cv2.circle(img, box[1], radius=0, color=(255, 255, 0), thickness=50)
        cv2.circle(img, box[3], radius=0, color=(255, 255, 0), thickness=50)
        # print(box)
        # print("\n")
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(img,
                      (x, y), (x + w, y + h),
                      (0, 255, 0),
                      2)
        aantal += 1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you facing this issue for other images?

Comment: Yes! I've included another image.

Comment: It is not cv2.boxPoints that is the issue, but the result from minAreaRect that may list vertices starting from different corners depending upon the rotation. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074165/order-of-corners-in-a-rotating-rectangle-in-opencv-python.  What is the top left corner when the the rectangle is rotated especially slightly ccw? In that case the "top-left" corner is lower than the top right corner. What is the top left corner when it is rotated 45 deg?

Comment: Ok I understand I think, but how can I change my code so it always takes the right corners, regardless of the angle?